# Peticiones Get autorizadas en base a permisos utilizando node js

Tags: nodejs, post, permisos

Lo que busco hacer es, que cada vez que un usuario, registrado o no, al solicitar o entrar a algún URL, quiero poder saber que usuario es, para ver si tiene acceso, y si lo tiene Renderizar la página con la información personal de dicho usuario.

Lo intenté solucionar creando un `controller` (llamado identificador) para cada una de las páginas disponibles en mi web. Dicho controller lo que hace es enviar al cliente a travez de `res.send()`, un `header` con un script(ini.js).

El script, ahora si me envía la información mediante el usuario( id session, id usuario...) mediante `POST`. A un controller diferente efectivamente.

Ahora si, que conozco quien es el usuario, y si tiene acceso o no, etc... Lo quiero re-dirigir `(res.redirect)` a la página original, el problema es que vuelve a ejecutar el `controller` (identificador) entonces esto se vuelve un ciclo. (De momento no renderizo )

No se si exista una solución más simple a este problema. He buscado bastante pero no encuentro nada que me sirva.

### EDITADO:

Hola! Perdón por el retraso estuve trabajando en esto, y creo que tengo una solución, y era con los cookies, no se porque tenia el concepto que el LocalStorage era un remplazo a los cookies, pero no, tienen funcionalidad completamente diferente.

Les muestro el código de como planeo solucionarlo:

routes.js:

```
/*Todas las paginas pasan por un controller para ver quienes son*/
'get /registroUsuarios.html': 'AccesosController.accesos',
```

AccesosController.js :

```
module.exports = {
       accesos: function(req, res) {
       sails.log.info('----------------------------------');
       sails.log.info('accesos()');
       sails.log.info('----------------------------------');

       res.cookie('codigo', '823789123798');
       res.cookie('usuario', '12345667');

       return res.view('registroUsuarios');
       }
};
```

Si por cada petición `get` que se realiza a cada página puedo ejecutar el controller, ya me permito revisar permisos, y renderizar. Creo que lo único tedioso de momento es tener que agregar todas las rutas de mi pagina en los `routes.js`.

A ver si a alguien le sirve o tiene una sugerencia. Saludos!

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: No conozco mucho de NodeJs pero esto parece más un problema de lógica que propiamente del framework-librería, y si guardas en sesión un indicador que diga si el usuario ya está logueado?, como el id del usuario o algo así, si esta variable de sesión está nula entra a tu controller si no simplemente la omite.

Comment: Yo uso passportjs y anda muy bien. Además podés probar http://npmjs.com/package/login-plus

Answer (score 0):

Con Node no necesitas poner el control de acceso a usuarios en cada get. Se puede usar el concepto de middleware y poner en un único get todo el control de acceso. Algo así como:

```
app.get('/public', function(res,req){
  // esto anda aún cuando no se esté logueado porque se ejecuta antes del control
});

// poner acá el control de usuario

app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.logged){
    res.end(401, "Debe loguearse <a href='/login'>aca</a>");
  }else{
    next(); // si está logueado continúa la ejecución de los siguientes get
  }
});
```

Para que funcione eso tiene que estar habilitado sessions y cookies. Para el control de usuario se podría poner algo así:

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res){
  if(req.body.usuario==='admin' && req.body.clave==='no_hacer_esto_en_produccion'){
    req.session.loggued = req.body.usuario;
    res.end("Ingreso correcto <a href='/menu'>seguir</a>");
  }else{
    res.end(401, "Ingreso incorrecto <a href='/login'>reintentar</a>");
  }
});

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
  res.end(
    "<form method=post action='/login'>"+
    "usuario<input name=usuario><br>"+
    "clave<input name=clave><br>"+
    "<input type=submit value='entrar'></form>"
  );
});
```

Para habilitar cookies y sesiones (además de agregarlo en el package.json) poner arriba.

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
```

y después de declarar app:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({ secret: 'bazinga', resave:false, saveUninitialized:true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estas usando sails js, si esto es correcto, la manera correcta de hacerlo es usando politicas *(policies)*: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies, asi que lo primero que tendrias que hacer seria una politica que te valide si tu usuario esta logueado o no, si es asi pasara al controller donde ya puedes hacer lo que quieras, puedes implementar cuantas politicas necesites. Segun mi experiencia esa es la forma correcta de hacerlo.